# What is the correct way to format cents and dollars in a grid column with a total?

Tags: usability, grid, formatting, numbers, money

I have a grid with columns that are formatted as cents and dollars. By default, the tender and amount columns are being formatted as integers, but for the total we are formatting it as 2 decimal places (.00).

```
tender   qty   amt

$5       1   5
$10      1   10
$100     1   100
5¢       1   5
10¢      1   10

total    5  115.15
```

What is the correct way to format the cents and dollars in the amount column?

Comment: The Tenders and amt are right aligned in actual grid... but not shown here

Answer (score 21):

Consistency is key here I think.
So, for currency, always use two decimals and [align every number to the right](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49944/best-practice-for-currency-input-fields/49946#49946).

It took me some time to make sense of the table you displayed in your post. I would go for something like this:

```
tender    qty    amt

  5.00      1      5.00
 10.00      1     10.00
100.00      1    100.00
  0.05      1      0.05
  0.10      1      0.10

total       5    115.15
```

Comment: You also want to align your headers the same way as the rest of the columns they're in, so the eye can scan down them cleanly. Usually, your first column is left aligned, and all other columns and headers are right aligned, to distinguish the lookup column from the data columns. [This book covers this sort of table formatting in great detail](http://www.amazon.com/Show-Me-Numbers-Designing-Enlighten/dp/0970601999)

Comment: Two decimals is correct for USD and many others but wrong for some currencies

Comment: Also, it would be good to keep the `$` (or `¥` or whatever) off to the side, to make it totally obvious what the number represents, rather than drop it completely

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keeping the amount in dollars at all times. 
Cent values can be shown as decimal dollar values.

Also, you can always have `tender` and `amt` columns to show values *right-aligned* and *up to 2 decimal places*. This will make values more presentable and less confusing.

Comment: I disagree, if the user is using the table to work out which physical coins useed in a transaction, which seems to be the intended purpose, then you want the lookup column to have the denominations of the coins/notes, not to be a dollar value for cent coins.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to display this in a UI, consider alternating the row background colors - between white and a faint/light color of your choice for easier reading.

You can choose to also style your headers row and totals row, but make sure they're readable.

In order to ensure proper right-alignment, **use a mono-spaced font.** The slightest misalignment of that decimal point is bothersome to many, which will happen if you use a font that has varying character widths.